# Monitor result of a bash command or shell script using Prometheus

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus

My requirement is to monitor the helpdesk system of the company which is running inside the Kubernetes cluster, for example, URL https://xyz.zendesk.com

They provide their [API set](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/status_api/status_api/) to monitor this efficiently.

We can easily check the status using **curl**

```
$ curl -s "https://status.zendesk.com/api/components/support?domain=xyz.zendesk.com" | jq '.active_incidents'
[]
```

The above output means success status according to **zendesk** documentation.

Now the main part is, the company uses Prometheus to monitor everything.

How to have Prometheus check the success status from the output of this curl command?.

I did some research already and found somewhat related threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659153/prometheus-monitoring-command-output-in-container) and using [pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway)

Are they applicable to my requirement or going in the wrong route?

Comment: Prometheus is running in the same cluster as zendesk?

Comment: Prometheus running inside a docker on an AWS instance, not from the same Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably (!?) want is something that:

1. Provides an HTTP(s) (e.g. `/metrics`) endpoint
2. Producing metrics in Prometheus' exposition format
3. From Zendesk's API

> **NOTE** `curl` only gives you #3

There are some examples of solutions that appear to meet the requirements but none is from Zendesk:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zendesk%22+prometheus+exporter

There are >2 other lists of Prometheus exporters (neither contains Zendesk):

- https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/
- https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations

I recommend you contact Zendesk and ask whether there's a Prometheus Exporter already. It's surprising to not find one.

It is straightforward to write a Prometheus Exporter. Prometheus [Client libraries](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) and Zendesk [API client](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/api-clients/introduction/) are available and preferred. While it's possible, bash is probably sub-optimal.

If **all** you want to do is GET that static endpoint, get a 200 response code and confirm that the body is `[]`, you may be able to use Prometheus [Blackbox exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter)

> **NOTE** Logging and monitoring tools often provide a higher-level tool that provides something analogous to a "universal translator", facilitating translation from 3rd-party systems' native logging|monitoring formats into some canonical form using config rather than code. Although in the logging space, [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) is an example. To my knowledge, there is no such tool for Prometheus but I sense that there's an opportunity for someone to create one.